# Looking for help with SAML Web Services and Netbeans 7

Tags: web-services, netbeans, saml, netbeans-7

[Google](http://www.google.com/?q=netbeans%207%20SAML) has failed me and [Netbeans 7](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/70/) is fairly new so I can't find any examples or tutorials yet. I'm using the sample **Secure Calculator App** that comes with Netbeans, its a simple web service with an *add* operation that adds two int's together.

If you click on Web Services -> CalculatorWS, then right-click (open context menu) -> Edit Web Service Attributes, then the "Secure Service" options supports

- SAML Authorization over SSL
- SAML Sender Vouches with Certificates
- SAML Holder of Key

[image: Netbeans Secure Service Screenshot]

And a bunch of STS (Secure Token Service) options, which I don't want to use an STS right now. **Which is the easiest to try, and how try them or make these SAML tokens?**

I'm very familiar with Web Services, just not SAML... or Netbeans (More of an Eclipse guy, but getting familiar with NB). I'm really just looking for a place to learn more about this, and if I can this simple example up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAML is really starting to take off... it's good to see. I'm way more familiar with it now. So if people have questions let me know.